# Table (ListObject) Assigning values using UDF

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, listobject

[image: Source Data]

Above is a simplified example but what I want to achieve with my UDF is to accept the string in the Collated column and a delimiter which will be used to break the sting apart into substrings and be assigned sequentially to the columns Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4. It is possible for there to be less than 4 substrings generated but there will never be more than 4.

```
Function DECONS(Subject As String, Delim As String) As String
' takes an input string "Subject" and seperates it using "Delim" as the deliminator
' If the desired element exceeds the number of unique substrings the function returns a blank result
' Hardcoded for max 4 substrings

' initializes temporary variables
Dim i As Long
Dim r() As String

' uses built in VBA function to split the passed string using the deliminating character
r = Split(Subject, Delim)

' increases the size of r() to 4 elements and fills extra elements with blancks
For i = UBound(r) + 1 To 3
ReDim Preserve r(i)
r(i) = ""
Next i

' my sad attempt at what I want to acheive
Dim loT As ListObject
Set loT = ThisWorksheet.ListObjects("TT")

For i = 1 To 4
loT.ListColumn(i + 1).Range.Value = r(i - 1)
Next i

End Function
```

I've done the text manipulation using the VBA split function which yields an array of strings but I'm hitting a wall as to how to assign the substrings to the relevant columns. My attempt can be seen above. I've done a fair bit of reading but I'm still not comfortable enough in VBA/Excel to figure this out on my own yet. Is this more complex when in a ListObject than outside a table object?

Unfortunately I can't return the string array from the function and then assign it to multiple cells as the Table Object doesn't allow array operations. I had a work around where I would return a specified element, ie the 3rd, and I would call the function in each column and output the one corresponding value. However, the method is not elegant and does a lot of unnecessary repeated computation.

Comment: Use Text-to-Columns on the data tab?

Comment: If you want to use a formula and you do not have an office 365 subscription then you will need to pass an index also, so you can tell it which on of the split array to return and every cell will need a formula in it.  If you have office 365 you should be able to return the array itself.  UDF cannot effect other cells than the one that called the UDF.

Comment: I've come across Text-to-Columns but if I'm not mistaken that needs to be actively selected by the user. Ultimately this would be part of a larger excel sheet and I want to limit the amount the user fiddles with it. I was hoping to automate it using alternate methods.

I also came across mention of a built in function which is only available on the subscription version but I don't currently have one and I don't necessarily want to use methods that may not be back compatible.

Comment: Ah, that is probably what had me stuck. I didn't realize the limitation that UDFs can only affect the cell they are in. I think I can have an intermediate column holding the array of strings and then pass that into the subsequent columns so that they don't each have do the string splitting. Appreciate your quick input!

Comment: What version do you have?  Depending on the version you can either put the formula only in the first column or you can array enter across the row.  But you will need to return the array from the UDF.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you about the version but I believe I tried array entering the formula but if the data is in a Table Object it won't allow it. I had it working as an array formula in a regular table previously.

Comment: that is correct, to limit the array you will want helper columns, or do an index and then put the formula in each cell.  Both have their draw backs. If you have office 365 with dynamic array formula it is a bit easier to create the helper columns.

Comment: BTW to do the index version: `Function DECONS(Subject As String, Delim As String, idx As Long) As String` and `DECONS = Split(Subject, Delim)(idx - 1)`  Then you would put this in the first cell: `=IFERROR(DECONS(Table1[@[Collated]:[Collated]],"\",COLUMN(A1)),"")` copy over and down

Comment: also just an FYI, to do this with formula only: `=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(Table1[@[Collated]:[Collated]],"\","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&COLUMN(A1)&"]"),"")`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Sub DECONS(Delim As String)
    Dim objList As ListObject
    Dim vDB As Variant, vSplit
    Dim vR(), n As Integer, r As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Set objList = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TT")
    vDB = objList.DataBodyRange.Columns(1)

    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 4)
    For i = 1 To r
        vSplit = Split(vDB(i, 1), "\")
        n = 0
        For Each v In vSplit
            n = n + 1
            vR(i, n) = v
        Next v
    Next i
    'Range("b2").Resize(r, 4) = vR
    objList.DataBodyRange.Columns(2).Range("a1").Resize(r, 4) = vR
End Sub
```